# Delete strings (support regex) stored in list from a text file

Tags: regex, string, replace, rpython

I'm trying to store a set of strings in a form of a list with the capability of supporting regular expressions and delete those strings from a file.

For example:

```
list = ['enabled','vs-index \d+']
```

- where 'vs-index \d' is expressed as an regex. (it can be .... vs-index 30, vs-index 40 . etc...)

I have a text file:

config.txt

```
ltm virtual testing { destination 80.80.80.80:https ip-protocol tcp mask 255.255.255.255 pool pool1 profiles { http { } tcp { } } source 0.0.0.0/0 source-address-translation { type automap } translate-address enabled translate-port enabled vs-index 38 }
ltm virtual blah { destination 50.50.50.50:https mask 255.255.255.255 profiles { fastL4 { } } source 0.0.0.0/0 translate-address enabled translate-port enabled vs-index 35 }
```

Expected output would be:

```
ltm virtual testing { destination 80.80.80.80:https ip-protocol tcp mask 255.255.255.255 pool pool1 profiles { http { } tcp { } } source 0.0.0.0/0 source-address-translation { type automap } translate-address enabled translate-port }
ltm virtual blah { destination 50.50.50.50:https mask 255.255.255.255 profiles { fastL4 { } } source 0.0.0.0/0 translate-address enabled translate-port }
```

The replace() function doesn't accept a list but rather a string. Any way possible to support a list and regex?

Comment: if you want to remove `vs-index 38`, it should be `vs-index \d+`. Otherwise it will just match `vs-index 3` and leave `8`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your list to a regexp that matches all the elements, and then use `re.sub()` to delete all the matches.

```
import re

l = ['enabled','vs-index \d+']
regex = re.compile('|'.join(l)) # 'enabled|vs-index d+'
with open("config.txt") as f:
    contents = f.read()
result = re.sub(regex, '', contents)
print(result)
```

Comment: I don't understand when you say "convert your list to a regexp that matches all the elements" because my elements can't be completely different, so it's hard to match everything...

Comment: Do you understand what `|` means in a regular expression? `pattern1|pattern2` matches both pattern1 and pattern2.

Comment: That's what I do with the `join()` function.

Comment: Humm.. I'm trying out the code but it's throwing me an error...

Comment: >>> import re
>>> l = ['enabled','vs-index \d+']
>>> regex = re.compile(l.join('|'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'
>>> with open("remove") as f:
...     contents = f.read()
...     
... 
>>> result = re.sub(regex, contents, '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
print(result)NameError: name 'regex' is not defined

Comment: I always forget that in Python `join()` is a string method, not a list method. Fixed it.

Comment: No errors now but no output...

Comment: >>> 
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> l = ['enabled','vs-index \d+']
>>> regex = re.compile('|'.join(l)) # 'enabled|vs-index d+'
>>> with open("remove") as f:
...     contents = f.read()
... 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> result = re.sub(regex, contents, '')
>>> print(result)

>>>

Comment: Oops I had the arguments to `re.sub()` in the wrong order.

Comment: Are you able to help fix the order?

Comment: Thank you sir!. works :)